# How can I add value to array in postgres if not contains

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Hello I want to update my data and my data looks like this:

```
list = {sad,dfgdf,vxcvxcv}
```

Which I used data type text[] in postgres.
I want to add for example **poc** to this array ("{sad,dfgdf,vxcvxcv}") if it doesn't contain poc and if poc is already inside that array, I don't want to update it. Is there any option to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@>` operator to check whether the array contains 'poc' and `array_append` to add it if not. Here is an illustration.

```sql
with t(x, y, arr) as
(
 values
 ('testa', 'BH06', '{sad,dfgdf,vxcvxcv}'::text[]),
 ('testb', 'BH07', '{das,fdgfd,abcbabc,poc}'),
 ('testc', 'BH08', '{}')
)
select x, y, 
    case when not arr @> '{poc}' then array_append(arr, 'poc') else arr end arr
from t;
```

Rsult:

| x | y | arr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| testa | BH06 | {sad,dfgdf,vxcvxcv,poc} |
| testb | BH07 | {das,fdgfd,abcbabc,poc} |
| testc | BH08 | {poc} |

Details on array operations [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html). Please note that double quotes are used for names  and single quotes for string literals in Postgresql.

An update query, supposing that the target column in your table is called `arr`:

```sql
update the_table 
    set arr = array_append(arr, 'poc')
where not arr @> '{poc}';
```

Comment: As I understand you should have the list before updating? I mean first I have to do a query and get the list then check it?

Comment: Well, no, I suppose that you already have a table with such columns. The `t` pseudo-table is just for illustration. You may use the actual table instead of `t`. Btw do you mean an update query?

Comment: Yes I want to update. Sorry for bad grammer

Comment: See updated answer. Accept it?